# JRE core dump. MapReduce running in Docker container

Tags: java, docker, jvm, coredump

I am running a docker container which is based on the : `openjdk:7-jre`
Inside that, I have a java MapReduce running causing a core dump as follows:

```
mapreduce@mapreduce:~$ cat hs_err_pid15.log 
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f68a214e687, pid=15, tid=140086747383552
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_181-b01) (build 1.7.0_181-b01)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.181-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.6.14
# Distribution: Debian GNU/Linux 8.10 (jessie), package 7u181-2.6.14-1~deb8u1
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x417687]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/mapreduce/core or core.15
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f67b80e0800):  JavaThread "LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0" [_thread_in_vm, id=732, stack(0x00007f687cc0c000,0x00007f687cd0d000)]
```

To run my MapReduce I use:

> VM Arguments: jvm_args: -XX:-UseLoopPredicate
>
> java_command:
>   current/jars/mapreduce-01.jar Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD
>
> Environment Variables:
>
> JAVA_HOME=/docker-java-home/jre
>
> PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

Any ideas what is causing it or where I should be looking. There is a lot of info in hs_err_pid15.log but I am not sure where to look?
Using `-XX:-UseLoopPredicate` did not solve the problem.

Comment: java 7? that has reached end of life. use a newer version, the issue may already have been fixed.

Comment: The project that I am building (java) compiles only on JAVA7.

Comment: Well, at least upload the rest of the `hs_err_pid` file somewhere.

Comment: @the8472 - I upgraded to JAVA8 and is looking much better. Thanks for your help